# Row cannot be found for Locate?

Tags: sql-server, delphi, sql-server-2005, ado, advantage-database-server

I'm converting existing Advantage Database Server application to SQL Server 2005 using D2009, dbGo (ADO). Sometimes i experience the error `row cannot be found for locating`. I had googled it, according to results i needed to set Update Criteria property of each ADOTable and set cursor location to dynamic. I did so, but sometimes i still get same error. All of the tables has primary key so I've been using

```
Query.Requery(); 
Query.Locate('ID',ID,[]);
```

before updating record to avoid error, but there has to be better solutions. Any ideas? Or should i move on to MyDAC or Zeoslib?

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone else has the same problem when using triggers, add   SET NOCOUNT ON  into beginning and SET NOCOUNT OFF  into end of trigger.

Comment: Please use comments. If you use the same account to login to this site every time you can add comments to your own questions.

Comment: Yes, I tried to comment but it requires 50 reputation - which I don't have.

Comment: Then edit your additional post with the clarifications or additional questions. :-) You can always edit your own posts.

Answer (score 2):

dbGO/ADO is the natural way to access MS-SQL databases. Are you sure that is the exact error message? Because I have never heard about it, but I have heard about "row cannot be **located** for **updating**".

That error message indicates that ADO can not find the record to be deleted or updated. Most often the cause is that the table does not have a primary key defined or there is at least no column in the table where the contents is all unique.

Make sure you define a primary key in your MS-SQL tables.

Answer (score 0):

The usual case for row cannot be updated is that you have default value constraints on the tables. Be sure to set values for the fields in OnNewRecord. 
You may also want to use 
myAdoDataset.Properties['Update Criteria'].Value := 0;
Then ADO should use only the key for updates.

Answer (score 0):

simple adotable1.refresh; after post should do the trick ...